# Kotlin Object OnComplete listener

Tags: kotlin

I need to know when my object is finally setup (gets data from internet) so I can properly use it without any nullpointerexceptions. Is there a way I can make an object notify when it's all setup, just like onComplete lambdas as function parameters. Simple question but anything helps :)

Comment: NullPointerExceptions should never occur in kotlin as long as you don't force unwrap. How do you get data from Internet? Generally any network call either accept a callback listener or block the thread. So you are probably either providing listener to the network call or do the network call on background thread to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @RickyMo I am getting data from Firebase Firestore. I can tell inside my object when it is completely setup but I don't know how to tell things outside of my object (my Android activity that holds the object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function type variable in your class. Set the function in your activity. Call it when your object is ready.

```
class MyObject()
{
    var onComplete : (()-> Unit)? = null

    fun setup()
    {
        //setup your object
        onComplete?.invoke()
    }
}
```

In your activity

```
val myObject = MyObject()
myObject.onComplete = {
    //..things to do after setup...
}
myObject.setup()
```

You can also put it in the constructor if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In android, we can use `LiveData` if you added support library dependency.

```
class Result

object MyObject {
    val onComplete: MutableLiveData<Result> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setUp() {
        // do something
        onComplete.setValue(Result()) // main thread
        // onComplete.postValue(Result()) // other thread
    }
}

class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MyObject.onComplete.observe(this, Observer { result ->
            // do something with result
        })
        MyObject.setUp()
    }
}
```

If this method is unfamiliar, check out observer pattern or LiveData.